# Run function over range in multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, rust

I have a function,

```rust
fn calculate(x: i64) -> i64 {
    // do stuff
    x
}
```

which I want to apply to a range

```rust
for i in 0..100 {
    calculate(i);
}
```

I want to multithread this though. I've tried different things: having an atomic `i` would be a good idea, but then I'd have to go into the details of shared ownership using libraries etc... is there a simple way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to run stuff on multiple threads and don't really care about the specifics, [`rayon`](https://docs.rs/rayon) might be helpful:

```
use rayon::prelude::*;

fn calculate(x: i64) -> i64 {
    x
}

fn main() {
    let results = (0..100i64)
        .into_par_iter()
        .map(calculate)
        .collect::<Vec<i64>>();
        
    
    println!("Results: {:?}", results);
}
```

This will automatically spin up threads based on how many cores you have and distribute work between them.

Answer (score 0):

Not really certain about what you want to achieve precisely, but here is a trivial example.

```rust
    let th: Vec<_> = (0..4) // four threads will be launched
        .map(|t| {
            std::thread::spawn(move || {
                let begin = t * 25;
                let end = (t + 1) * 25;
                for i in begin..end { // each one handles a quarter of the overall computation
                    let r = calculate(i);
                    println!("t={} i={} r={}", t, i, r);
                }
            })
        })
        .collect();
    for t in th { // wait for the four threads to terminate
        let _ = t.join();
    }
```